# How to store integer value from int variable in char variable?

Tags: c++, string

```
int d = names.size() - 2;
    char c = char(d);

return names[0] + ", " + names[1] + " and " + c + " others like this";
```

Now, I have to return the number of people stored in variable "d" as a single string but as "d" is an integer, it cannot be directly added. So, what should I do to store the value of "d" as a string or char to add in the return string?

Comment: `std::to_string()`

Comment: Note:  An integer variable has a wider range than a `char` variable.  You may not be able to assign an integer variable to a single `char` variable.

Answer (score 0):

`std::ostringstream` will help you a lot here, as you can simply write values of different types (e.g. strings and numbers) to it.

In the example below I use it together with the `<fmt>` library, but you could use the `<format>` library instead (C++20, MSVC), or just write to `oss` as you would write to `std::cout`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/9YqKKvad6)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <sstream>  // ostringstream
#include <string>
#include <vector>

auto f(const std::vector<std::string>& names) {
    if (names.size() >= 2) {
        int d = names.size() - 2;
        std::ostringstream oss{};
        oss << fmt::format("{}, {} and {} others like this", names[0], names[1], d);
        return oss.str();
    }
    return std::string{};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> names{ "Anne", "Brian", "Charlize", "Daniel" };
    std::cout << f(names);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   Anne, Brian and 2 others like this
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there are two different types of string: `char` arrays and `std::string`.

**std::string [Easiest approach.]**

`std::string`s behave similarly to strings in other programming languages (they can be concatenated, ). To convert an `int` to an `std::string`, use `std::to_string(val)` (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

*I would avoid using C-style strings here as they have a fixed size and need to be deleted manually.*